# how to install an binary and execute it from other folders 12.10

Tags: installation, 12.10

I downloaded the `jq` JSON processing library from http://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/ and ran `./jq` and it seems to work great.

How do I "install" it into my Ubuntu 12.10 so it runs from other directories?

---

This question is so basic that it's actually very difficult to search.  However, I do not know which word for search for in Google or where in the Ubuntu docs this might be.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a link to the binary in one of the directories in your path.  You can check which those are by running:

```
echo $PATH
```

but the best place to put it is probably /usr/local/bin/ like so:

```
ln -s ./jq /usr/local/bin/
```